# Close Button Not Working in Swift Playground

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, swift-playground

I am working on a Swift playground for WWDC. I need to have a UI Button that closes the web view and toolbars (the button is called closeButton and the function is at the bottom for the button), and returns to the previously screen when clicked (the first view). The code below is the Swift I have typed so far:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    let cardView = UIView()
    let accountButton = UIButton()
    let coverImageView = UIImageView()
    let swiftLogoView = UIImageView()
    let openLabel = UILabel()
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let label = UILabel()
    let captionLabel = UILabel()
    let descriptionLabel = UILabel()
    let backgroundImageView = UIImageView()
    let closeButton = UIButton()
    let openButton = UIButton()
    let doneButton = UIButton()
    let url1 = URL(string: "https://youtube.com/embed/uuxXHAKA1WY")!
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Who Made This Playground:", message: "Mark Bruckert made this playground for WWDC 2018. He is a Web and Graphic Designer learning Swift and IOS Design. He would love to attend this year, to learn the new frameworks revealed at the event and have IOS Engineers review his designs and code.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .default, handler: nil)
    let menuBar = UIView()
    let doneLabel = UILabel()
    let webView = UIWebView()

    let cardView2 = UIView()
    let coverImageView2 = UIImageView()
    let titleLabel2 = UILabel()
    let captionLabel2 = UILabel()
    let descriptionLabel2 = UILabel()
    let backgroundImageView2 = UIImageView()
    let url2 = URL(string: "https://youtu.be/uuxXHAKA1WY")!

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        label.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 30, width: 272, height: 38)
        label.text = "Dev Tutorials:"
        label.textColor = .black
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 32, weight: .bold)

        openLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 140, y: 215, width: 272, height: 38)
        openLabel.text = "Play Video"
        openLabel.textColor = .black
        openLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 32, weight: .semibold)
        self.openLabel.alpha = 0
        openLabel.layer.zPosition = 5

        doneLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 25, y: 5, width: 272, height: 38)
        doneLabel.text = "Done"
        doneLabel.textColor = .white
        doneLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 32, weight: .light)
        openLabel.layer.zPosition = 7
        doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doneButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside
        )

        cardView.frame = CGRect(x: 60, y: 100, width: 300, height: 250)
        cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 14
        cardView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        cardView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
        cardView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 10)
        cardView.layer.shadowRadius = 10

        cardView2.frame = CGRect(x: 60, y: 100, width: 300, height: 250)
        cardView2.layer.cornerRadius = 14
        cardView2.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        cardView2.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
        cardView2.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 10)
        cardView2.layer.shadowRadius = 10

        titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 16, width: 272, height: 38)
        titleLabel.text = "Portals with ARKit"
        titleLabel.textColor = .white
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 32, weight: .semibold)

        captionLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 204, width: 272, height: 40)
        captionLabel.text = "by Jared Davidson"
        captionLabel.textColor = .white
        captionLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        descriptionLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 400, width: 335, height: 132)
        descriptionLabel.text = "In this tutorial, you will learn how to use ARKit by Apple to transport yourself through a portal."
        descriptionLabel.textColor = .black
        descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 10
        descriptionLabel.alpha = 0

        coverImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 250)
        coverImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        coverImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cover.jpg")
        coverImageView.clipsToBounds = true

        swiftLogoView.frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: 8, width: 35, height: 35)
        swiftLogoView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        swiftLogoView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Swift_logo.png")
        swiftLogoView.clipsToBounds = true
        coverImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 14

        accountButton.frame = CGRect(x: 360, y: 20, width: 55, height: 55)
        accountButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.803921580314636, green: 0.803921580314636, blue: 0.803921580314636, alpha: 1.0)
        accountButton.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        accountButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(accountButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        closeButton.frame = CGRect(x: 360, y: 20, width: 28, height: 28)
        closeButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        closeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 14
        closeButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Action-Close@2x.png"), for: .normal)
        closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        closeButton.alpha = 0

        openButton.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 220, height: 75)
        openButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        openButton.layer.cornerRadius = 14
        openButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        openButton.alpha = 0

        doneButton.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 130, height: 50)
        doneButton.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
        doneButton.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        doneButton.layer.cornerRadius = 14
        doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doneButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)


        cardView.addSubview(coverImageView)


        cardView.addSubview(openLabel)

        doneButton.addSubview(doneLabel)
        cardView.addSubview(closeButton)

        cardView.addSubview(openButton)

        menuBar.addSubview(doneButton)
        cardView.addSubview(descriptionLabel)

        view.addSubview(cardView)

        view.addSubview(label)

        view.addSubview(accountButton)

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(cardViewTapped))
        cardView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        cardView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        doneButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        self.view = view
    }

    @objc func cardViewTapped() {
        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.7, dampingRatio: 0.7) {
            self.cardView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 450, height: 667)

            self.label.layer.isHidden = true
            self.cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 0
            self.titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 374, height: 38)
            self.captionLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 370, width: 272, height: 40)
            self.descriptionLabel.alpha = 1
            self.coverImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 450, height: 420)
            self.coverImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 0

            self.closeButton.alpha = 1

            self.openButton.alpha = 0.7

            self.accountButton.alpha = 0

            self.openLabel.alpha = 1
        }
        animator.startAnimation()
    }

    @objc func closeButtonTapped() {
        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.7, dampingRatio: 0.7) {
            self.cardView.frame = CGRect(x: 60, y: 100, width: 300, height: 250)
            self.cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 14
            self.titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 16, width: 272, height: 38)
            self.captionLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 204, width: 272, height: 40)
            self.descriptionLabel.alpha = 0
            self.coverImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 250)
            self.coverImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 14
            self.closeButton.alpha = 0

            self.label.layer.isHidden = false

            self.openButton.alpha = 0

            self.openLabel.alpha = 0

            self.accountButton.alpha = 1
        }
        animator.startAnimation()
    }

    @objc func openButtonTapped() {

        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 600))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view

        menuBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(menuBar)
        menuBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        menuBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        menuBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        menuBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64.0).isActive = true
        menuBar.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.803921580314636, green: 0.803921580314636, blue: 0.803921580314636, alpha: 1.0)

        let toolbar = UIView()
        toolbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(toolbar)
        toolbar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        toolbar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        toolbar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        toolbar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64.0).isActive = true
        toolbar.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.803921580314636, green: 0.803921580314636, blue: 0.803921580314636, alpha: 1.0)

        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuBar.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: toolbar.topAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
        webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string:"https://youtube.com/embed/uuxXHAKA1WY")!))
    }

    @objc func accountButtonTapped() {
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
    }

    @objc func doneButtonTapped() {
        self.webView.alpha = 0
        self.view.alpha = 0
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Thanks in advance for your help,
Mark B.

Comment: Does the above code work? I pasted it in my Playground and it doesnt run

Comment: The reason it's not working for you @Harish is that you don't have the `.png` files in a Resource folder that Mark (the OP) has.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Thank you for answering this question for me... that is the reason why the code did not run for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In method **openButtonTapped**, Local variable **view** created problem to your code. Also, you called **liveView** again. I have modified your code, it is working assumed that last screen will go to previous.

First, declare the **toolBar** as member variable like **menuBar**.And you the following code. Tap done button will go to previous.

```
 @objc func openButtonTapped() {
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    menuBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(menuBar)
    menuBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    menuBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    menuBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    menuBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64.0).isActive = true
    menuBar.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.803921580314636, green: 0.803921580314636, blue: 0.803921580314636, alpha: 1.0)

    toolbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(toolbar)
    toolbar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    toolbar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    toolbar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    toolbar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64.0).isActive = true
    toolbar.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.803921580314636, green: 0.803921580314636, blue: 0.803921580314636, alpha: 1.0)


    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(webView)
    webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuBar.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
    webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: toolbar.topAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
    webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string:"https://youtube.com/embed/uuxXHAKA1WY")!))
}

@objc func accountButtonTapped() {
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
}

@objc func doneButtonTapped() {
    print("test")
    self.webView.stopLoading()
    self.webView.alpha = 0
    toolbar.removeFromSuperview()
    menuBar.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... you are a lifesaver! These changes fixed the problems I was having.

Comment: @user9550112, you are welcome and please accept my answer as it is working.